# Regex to extract the last consecutive alphabetical characters occurring immediately before the file extension in a filename

Tags: c#, regex

How can I use regular expressions to extract the last consecutive alphabetical characters occurring immediately before the file extension in a filename?

For instance, in filenames like 'FileName_2015-01-23 CODE.txt' or 'FileName_2015-01-23CODE.txt', I aim to capture the word 'CODE', which directly precedes the file extension (.txt).

Comment: What is _concurrent alpha_ exactly mean?

Comment: Whats the question? [ask]

Comment: You can use `\w+(?=\.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's guaranteed to be formatted like the example you've given (numbers before the final alpha characters), you can use something simple like

`([a-zA-Z]+)\.txt`

Which should return two groups. The first group (index of 0) will be the bit you want (`CODE`, from the example given) and the second (index of 1) will be the `.txt` portion. Or it might return three groups with the first (index 0) being the full text, 1 being the grouping you want, and 2 being the `.txt`. I could be wrong on that one, that's something I've experienced only with PHP and I'm honestly way too tired to be answering this.

Comment: heh, yeah, that'd throw my regex off. If the format of the example given is going to remain as such it'd be fine, but if it could at least be guaranteed that there will be a space before the consecutive alpha characters the asker is looking for, then my regex could be revised to `\s([a-zA-Z]+)\.txt`

Edit: oh, well, a person HAD asked me what if the file name looked like `FileName.txt_2015-01-23 CODE.txt` but that seems to be removed

Comment: thnks .. it workes for me..